# RestKit - Undeclared identifier 'DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL' inside RKObjectManager?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, restkit

Trying to setup and get going with the RestKit library for a cocoa project (NOT iOS) and have followed the instructions precisely at  [RestKit Installation on Xcode 4.x as a Git Submodule](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

The issue now is when I try and run and I get the following issue inside `RKObjectManager` when RestKit tries to compile for the first time:

```
 defaultMappingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("org.restkit.ObjectMapping", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

> Undeclared identifier 'DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL' ?!

Any ideas what may be causing this? I'm linking all the correct libraries to the target as stated in the instructions.

Comment: What SDK are you compiling with? `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` is only available on OS X 10.7+/iOS 5.0+

Comment: @Wevah ack! I'm on OS X 10.6 - Since this is part of native RestKit I guess I need to revert to an earlier build then which supports 10.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` is only defined on the OS X 10.7+/iOS 5.0+ SDKs. If you're building with an older SDK, you can pass `NULL` for the second parameter to `dispatch_queue_create()`. (Private concurrent queues won't work on older OSs, though.)